# Find Group of Characters From String

Tags: c++, string, replace, find

I did a program to remove a group of Characters From a String. I have given below that coding here.

```
void removeCharFromString(string &str,const string &rStr)
{
     std::size_t found = str.find_first_of(rStr);
  while (found!=std::string::npos)
  {
    str[found]=' ';
    found=str.find_first_of(rStr,found+1);
  }
    str=trim(str);


}

 std::string str ("scott<=tiger");

 removeCharFromString(str,"<=");
```

as for as my program, I got my output Correctly. Ok. Fine. If I give a value for str as "scott=tiger" , Then the searchable characters "<=" not found in the variable str. But my program also removes '=' character from the value 'scott=tiger'. But I don't want to remove the characters individually. I want to remove the characters , if i only found the group of characters '<=' found. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `find_first_of` looks for any character in the input, in your case, any of '<' or '='. In your case, you want to use [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

```
std::size_t found = str.find(rStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer works on the assumption that you only want to find the set of characters in the exact sequence e.g. If you want to remove `<=` but not remove `=<`:

`find_first_of` will locate any of the characters in the given string, where you want to find the whole string.

You need something to the effect of:

```
std::size_t found = str.find(rStr);
while (found!=std::string::npos)
{
    str.replace(found, rStr.length(), " ");
    found=str.find(rStr,found+1);
}
```

The problem with `str[found]=' ';` is that it'll simply replace the first character of the string you are searching for, so if you used that, your result would be

```
scott =tiger
```

whereas with the changes I've given you, you'll get

```
scott tiger
```